# Animations in Chrome 34

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-animations

I used a snippet from here a while back to create a infinitely scrolling element https://css-tricks.com/infinite-all-css-scrolling-slideshow/

The active code I'm using on my website looks like:

```
.wave_bg {
  background: url("../img/wave_bg.jpg") no-repeat;
  -webkit-animation: slide 10s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: slide 10s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: slide 10s linear infinite;
  animation: slide 10s linear infinite;
}

  @-webkit-keyframes slide {
    from {
      background-position: 0 0;
    }
    to {
      background-position: 100% 0;
    }
  }
  @-moz-keyframes slide {
    from {
      background: left;
    }
    to {
      background: right;
    }
  }
  @-ms-keyframes slide {
    from {
      background: left;
    }
    to {
      background: right;
    }
  }
  @keyframes slide {
    from {
      background: left;
    }
    to {
      background: right;
    }
  }
```

However in Chrome 34 this suddenly stopped working (it worked in Chrome 33 and earlier) - the background image just doesn't appear at all (it works in FF 33.1, FF 35.0.1, FF 38.0.5 and IE 10 still). If I disable the animation (and deprecated -webkit-animation) in dev tools then the background image shows again - so I'm assuming the issue is related to the CSS animation.

I can't find (at a quick search around) any documentation on things changing in Chrome 34 with regards to animations - so I was wondering if anyone had experienced this bug and had some sort of workaround for it?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at your code.. but... as Chrome drops more and more prefixes, some of your animations may not work if for example your only using `-webkit` prefixes in you `-webkit-animation: infinite...`.

Make sure you use both prefixed and unprefixed syntax within your delcared animations basically. See below...

You need this...

```
@-webkit-keyframes infnite {
    0%   { -webkit-transform: scale(1); transform: scale(1);}
    100% { -webkit-transform: scale(2); transform: scale(1);}
}
```

**and this...**

```
@keyframes infnite {
    0%   { -webkit-transform: scale(1); transform: scale(1);}
    100% { -webkit-transform: scale(2); transform: scale(1);}
}
```

In the above example... if Chrome dropped support for `transform` prefix but not for `keyframes` then unless u have both the prefix and unprefix your animation will stop working *"suddenly"*.

Comment: The snippet in the question above is the CSS used on the site and contains both prefixed and unprefixed versions. FWIW chrome does recognize the prefixed versions though because i need to uncheck both the animation and the -webkit-animation for the background image to 'reappear'

Comment: Can you actually supply your code. It's difficult to diagnose without it as the example you showed on CSS-Tricks does not adhere to what i have said.

Comment: I have - it is the code snippet in the stackoverflow question itself :)

Comment: no.. you haven't included the animation. only the call to the animation.

Comment: Sorry I must have misread first time or something :/ Added in now

Comment: In my answer, i have included examples of both prefixed and non prefixed keyframes. You NEED to include both prefixed and non-prefixed css inside the NON prefixed animation. Like in my example.

Comment: Hope this all helps anyway, it confused me the first time i noticed it :)